# Error: Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to delete a user by id. I am already able to search for a user by id and update (edit) a user by id. However, I'm having trouble with deletion.

Here is the error I'm getting (Whitelabel page error):

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:417)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:364)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:491)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

User.java

```
package com.springbootbasics;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name= "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;
    private String name;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
    public User(long id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    
}
```

UserController.java

```
package com.springbootbasics;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userData;

        @GetMapping("/results")
        public ModelAndView getPage() {
            User usr = new User();
            return new ModelAndView("searchUsers", "fn", usr);       
        }

        @PostMapping("/results")
        public ModelAndView find(@RequestParam long id) {
            User usr = userData.findById(id).get();
            return new ModelAndView("results", "hello", usr);       
        }
        
        @GetMapping("/editemp")
        public ModelAndView getupdate(@RequestParam long id) {
            User usr = userData.findById(id).get();
            return new ModelAndView("update", "edit", usr);
        }
        @PostMapping("/editemp")
        public RedirectView updateEmp(User usr) {
            userData.save(usr);
            return new RedirectView("listemp");
        }
        
        //
        
        
        @DeleteMapping("/deletetemp")
        public RedirectView deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id)  
        {  
            userData.deleteById(id);
            return new RedirectView("listemp");
        } 
        
        //
    
        @GetMapping("/listemp")
        public ModelAndView listEmp() {
            List<User> allUsers = (List<User>) userData.findAll();
            return new ModelAndView("allUsers","employee", allUsers);
        }
}
```

allUsers.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<body>

<h1>User page</h1>
<ul>
<c:forEach items="${employee}" var="user">
   <li>${user.id}</li>
   <li>${user.name}</li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

results.jsp

```
<%-- <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${temp}" var="user">

            <tr>
                <td>${user.id}</td>
                <td>${user.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html> --%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>List of Employees</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color: blue"></h1>

    <form:form action="find" method="post" modelAttribute="hello">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>${hello.id}<form:hidden path="id" name="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>${hello.name}<form:hidden path="id" name="name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a type="button" href="/editemp?id=${hello.id}">Update</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a type="button" href="/deletetemp?id=${hello.id}">Delete</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>

    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

searchUsers.jsp

```
<%-- <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${temp}" var="user">

            <tr>
                <td>${user.id}</td>
                <td>${user.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html> --%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>List of Employees</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color: blue"></h1>

    <form:form action="find" method="post" modelAttribute="hello">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>${hello.id}<form:hidden path="id" name="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>${hello.name}<form:hidden path="id" name="name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a type="button" href="/editemp?id=${hello.id}">Update</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a type="button" href="/deletetemp?id=${hello.id}">Delete</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>

    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

update.jsp

```
<%-- <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html> --%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Update Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color: blue">List of Employees</h1>
    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="edit">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>${edit.id}<form:hidden path="id" name="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

This all works fine except when the user clicks 'Delete', then I get the error shown above.

Comment: Not sure what the error message means in this case because I would have expected a *"Request method 'POST' not supported"* - but the gist is the same: you need to not make a GET request or POST request, but an actual DELETE request which seems not possible by bare html https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms

Comment: I know it's possible to do a deletion, because I know other's who have done it, however maybe not with bare html. Do I need to add a new .java file like UserService or something? If you aren't sure np.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in "results.jsp" you are calling "/deletetemp?id=${hello.id}" on click of "Delete" button. This scenario will invoke HTTP GET Request NOT HTTP DELETE. (Can be verified in header section using Browser console)

@DeleteMapping is used in context of RESTful Service APIs implementation. You can explicitly pass HTTP DELETE Method in REST Service call to execute method annotated with @DeleteMapping to handle DELETE functionality.

So I would recommend to handle this execution by @GetMapping as you are doing for Edit functionality.

Comment: I am trying to delete the user from the DB using @DeleteMapping.....You're saying I should use GetMapping instead of DeleteMapping?

Comment: Yes @SeanHungerford as you are currently in scope of Web Application so you are left with HTTP GET and POST methods only. Although you may send DELETE or other Methods also using explicit scripting by Javascript/JQuery but that is not standard way.

Comment: Could you do me a huge favor and show me what my GetMapping should look like? I am getting erros like "Cannot convert string "id" to long "id"" when I used GetMapping. Maybe edit your answer post or something

Comment: Can you please paste what exact url is getting called when you click on "Delete".

Comment: I actually got it working, thanks for the help.

Comment: **!!! This is dangerously wrong advice !!!** Neither update nor delete should be `GET` calls, this is incorrect in terms of REST, will cause the browser to cache incorrectly and is a major security risk, e.g. when dealing with cross-site Cookies which the browser automatically appends for GETs but not for POSTs and DELETEs (unless SameSite=Strict). Additionally GET will not issue CORS preflight requests meaning your entire site is attackable using CSRF.

Comment: Yes @luk2302 you are absolutely right, but here the assumption is the application is just a POC and not to follow best practices. The advice given was to make this thing work with minimal changes which is also not in context of REST.